# Documentation on https://www.dropbox.com/1/connect?k=XXXXX

Tags: dropbox-api

i have encountered several apps using https://www.dropbox.com/1/connect?k=XXXXX url to request authorisation to their apps but I can't find official documentation on the dropbox site... on dropbox... they have documentation on oauth authentication where you must request authorisation code and then fetch your token but it requires that you have an ssl website

Any idea how to use https://www.dropbox.com/1/connect?k=XXXXX instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of Dropbox's mobile SDKs use this endpoint, but if you're not using one of those SDKs, I definitely recommend just using the documented OAuth endpoints.

If you're building a mobile app, I recommend using a scheme like `db-<APP_KEY>://` for a redirect URI, just as the mobile SDKs do. There's no need to redirect to a website; you can just redirect back to your app.

It may be worth reading the code for the Android or iOS SDKs to see how they do authorization before building your own implementation.

**EDIT**: It occurs to me that you might not be building a mobile app at all. If that's the case, a little more context about what you're building might help.

Comment: I am developing a mobile app.

Comment: I actually first tried a custom scheme but dropbox returned an error saying that only https scheme are accepted :(

Comment: @yeahman I just tried adding `db-test://callback` as a redirect URI for one of my apps, and it worked fine. Can you give more detail about when and where you're seeing an error?

Comment: I am using this tutorial: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/07/using-oauth-2-0-with-the-core-api/

https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<app key>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=myapp://test&state=<CSRF token>

I gives me an error ... Maybe I need to add myapp://test in the redirect url of my dropbox account??

Comment: Yes, you need to add whatever redirect URI you're going to use in the App Console.

Comment: i still get "invalid redirect_uri":  When response_type=code, redirect_uri must start with httpS://, unless it's a localhost URI

Comment: You should probably be using the token flow, not the code flow. (Try `response_type=token`.)

Comment: thx! yup response_type=token does not require an https redirect uri!